# Object wont move based on angle given?

Tags: java, angle, degrees, radians

So I've been trying to make an object move based on two speeds that it creates using atan().
But every test results in the same movement of going straight up.

So I decided to take that out and replace it with inputted angles which oddly does only work for the the four angles 90 180 270 0.

I'm not sure why it only goes for only those for directions here's my code:

```
public void update() {

    updateDir();
    move();
}

public void updateDir(){
    dir = Math.atan(spdY/spdX);


    dir =20; //I know this is here it was used to test if it will actually change
    dir = dir * Math.PI / 180.0;
    System.out.println("dir: " + dir);
}


public void move() {
    x +=   (spd*Math.cos(dir));
    y -=  (spd * Math.sin(dir));
}
```

Any reason why it only goes in 4 directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What *@Nishant Shreshth* says is true. But it is also super important to use floating points (like `float` or `double`) instead of `int` for your `dir`, `x` and `y` variable. Otherwise the decimal part your `dir` value might be truncated, which is pretty much of a problem when you use radians and trigonometric functions.

Also note that you probably want to use `Math.atan2(spdY, spdX)` instead of the default atan method you use. Your approach will fail as soon as `spdX` gets zero: you will divide by zero. `atan2` will take care of these edge cases. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) gives details on this function.

Comment: Well dir is double (sorry for not puting this in), but I will try casting the 20 to a double. Also,your right on the atan thing I forgot about it and will change it soon.

Comment: Make sure x and y are doubles. I suspect them to be int.

Answer (score 3):

Did you realize that the `dir` field never changes in your code.

Method `updateDir` prints the same thing no matter how many times you call it.

What's `dir = 20` for? I guess you might need to recheck or get rid of that statement.

Comment: Ayyyy, he assigns it and then *re-assigns* it to a constant value. 1+

Comment: I just used it to test. The thing is that is still going straight up instead of actually going 20 degrees.